# SQLAlchemy Commit Changes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Inside of the declarative base I define a function like this:

```
def update_me(self):
   if self.raw_info==1: self.changed_info=10
   else: self.changed_info=20
```

I know this can be done with hybrid_property but I actually do more complicated manipulations, the above is just for illustrative purposes, this has to be done through a method.  How can I commit these changes, from inside the declarative base, without passing it the session object? It seems logical that there would be a way, if I can access the object and change its values without a session object, then it seems like I should be able to save it here somehow.  Of course adding this code to the end of the function above fails

```
self.commit()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there would be any mechanism to do this. Committing is an expensive operation, and usually done once, after all the updates have been made. Generally, it's not a good idea to call an expensive operation in a setter method.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea to me, and not just because committing would be an "expensive" operation: more to the point, SQLAlchemy is based around the idea of separating your business logic from your persistence logic. Anyone using your code (including yourself a few months down the line) will now need to carefully determine which methods they can safely call without causing the session to be committed prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you might want to reconsider your design. However, if you are sure you want to go this way, you can use the [`object_session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html?highlight=object_sessi#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.object_session) method:

```
object_session(self).commit()
```

**Warning:** This will commit your *whole* session (not just one object) and it will only work if `self` is already attached to a session (by `Session.add` or having queried for it, for example). Thus, it will be a fragile operation and I would not recommend it unless absolutely necessary.

But you are right, when you say

> It seems logical that there would be a way, if I can access the object and change its values without a session object, then it seems like I should be able to save it here somehow.

The object and the session are connected and thus changes will be delivered to the database. We get this connected session with the method above.